# loop through array values in jmeter Json path and assert each value

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I have this filtered JSON response from Json Path exression

> [40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,45,45,45,45,45,42,45,42,45,42,41,40,35,37,35,45,42,41,40,35,37,35,45,42,41,40,35,37,35,45]

I need to write some assertion which will basically assert these values are in a range ex: between 30 and 60.
I am not getting any pointers on how to assert this in jmeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter doesn't offer appropriate Test Elements so you will have to do some scripting.

The below code assumes JMeter version is equal or higher than 3.0. For earlier JMeter versions you will have to put [Json-smart](http://netplex.github.io/json-smart/) libraries somewhere in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

1. Add [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) after the JSON Path PostProcessor
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell Assertion "Script" area

   ```
   import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
   import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;
   import org.apache.commons.lang.math.IntRange;


   String source = vars.get("yourVar");

   IntRange range = new IntRange(30, 60);

   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(JSONParser.MODE_JSON_SIMPLE);
   JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(source);
   for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
       int value = (int) array.get(i);
       if (!range.containsInteger(value)) {
           Failure = true;
           FailureMessage = "Detected value: " + value + " is not in the expected range";

       }

   }
   ```

   If the value outside the given range will be found the Beanshell Assertion will fail the parent sampler

   [image: Beanshell assertion in work]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on enhancing your JMeter tests with scripting.

Comment: worked like a charm. your 25k reputation speaks for itself .

Comment: Bol'shoye spasibo